# Creating parameters pack based on another pack from template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

Suppose there are several template classes (structures), objects of which form the sequence - let's call them **N_mod**(N - specifier for particular class), and special class, that defines the first element in the sequence - **First_mod**. Each class, except **First_mod**, has its own "interface builder" - **N_builder** - template class:

```
template<int targ>
struct First_mod //First element in sequence - without appropriate builder interface
{   };

//Let's consider two types of N_mod - A_mod and B_mod
template<int targ, int param>
struct A_mod
{   };

template<int param>
struct A_builder//Builder for A_mod objects
{   };

template<int targ, int param>
struct B_mod
{   };

template<int param>
struct B_builder//Builder for B_mod objects
{   };
```

Now I need to generate sequence of **First_mod** and **N_mod** objects from existing sequense of appropriate **N_builders** in accordance with simple rule:

> *if* **N_Mod(i)** *equals* **A_mod** *then* targ(i) = param(i) - targ(i-1),
>
> *else*(i.e. **N_Mod(i)** *equals* **B_mod**) targ(i) = param(i) * targ(i-1)

My sketches for clarity:

```
template<typename...builders>
struct mod_seq_gen
{
    typedef /*generated First_mod, A_mod and B_mod sequence pack. How to do it?*/ modseq;
};

template<typename...builders>
struct Container
{
    std::tuple</*here must be mod-sequence generator that creates
                mod parameters pack and unpacks them:*/
                mod_seq_gen<builders...>::modseq
              > mod_sequence;
};

int main()
{   
    /*In this case must be generated next sequence and stored in 
     * mod_sequence tuple:
     * First_mod<3> - A_mod<5-3, 5> - B_mod<2*(5-3), 2>
     */
    Container<First_mod<3>, A_builder<5>, B_builder<2>> obj;
}
```

I'm asking to help in the implementation of **mod_seq_gen**, or some other tips for the whole task.

Comment: Either your formula, your example or the order of template parameters for **N_mod** is wrong. If `A_mod<5-3, 5>` means targ(1) = 2, param(1) = 5, then the formula must be targ(i) = param(i) - targ(i-1) for **A_mod**.

Comment: @DyP, yes, I'm wrong. Fixed.

Comment: After writing the thing and getting wrong output, I was worried ;) (normally, if those things compile, they're correct)

Comment: I guess it could be a bit simpler if there was a builder for the first type, too (even if it did nothing). You could get rid of the "special case" in the recursion (specialization of `gen` and a second concatenation typedef for the tuple).

Comment: @DyP, I was thinking about builder for first type, but I assumed that  it would be better without them))) I'm wrong again)))

Comment: See the edit to my answer for a version with `First_builder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll dump the (compiling) solution:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<int targ>
struct First_mod //First element in sequence - without appropriate builder interface
{  void print() { std::cout << "First_mod["<<targ<<"]" << std::endl; }  };

//Let's consider two types of N_mod - A_mod and B_mod
template<int targ, int param>
struct A_mod
{  void print() { std::cout << "A_mod["<<targ<<", "<<param<<"]" << std::endl; }  };

template<int param>
struct A_builder//Builder for A_mod objects
{
    // publish the template parameter (not necessary)
    static const int param_value = param;

    // provide a way to compute the current targ
    static constexpr int calc_targ(int prev_targ)
    {
        return param - prev_targ;
    }

    // provide a way to build the type
    template < int targ >
    using type = A_mod<targ, param>;
};

template<int targ, int param>
struct B_mod
{  void print() { std::cout << "B_mod["<<targ<<", "<<param<<"]" << std::endl; }  };

template<int param>
struct B_builder//Builder for B_mod objects
{
    static const int param_value = param;
    static constexpr int calc_targ(int prev_targ)
    {
        return prev_targ * param;
    }

    template < int targ >
    using type = B_mod<targ, param>;
};


// just a helper, wonder if there's something in the Standard Library o.O
template < typename... Tuples >
using tuple_cat_types = decltype(tuple_cat( std::declval<Tuples>()... ));


// the generator of the tuple
template < typename TFirst_mod, typename... TBuilders >
struct gen;

// restrict the first type to a specialization of `First_mod`
// isn't necessary, strictly speaking. We just need the first targ.
// Could as well require a nested `static const int targ = ..;`
template < int first_targ, typename... TBuilders >
struct gen < First_mod<first_targ>, TBuilders... >
{
    // recursive helper for the types to be built
    // general case for no template arguments in the pack
    template < int prev_targ, typename... TBuilders2 >
    struct helper { using type = std::tuple<>; };

    // specialized case for recursion
    // note: the recursion here occurs as a nested typedef, not inheritance
    //       (simplifies use of calculated targ)
    template < int prev_targ, typename TBuilder, typename... TBuilders2 >
    struct helper<prev_targ, TBuilder, TBuilders2...>
    {
        // build type using builder
        static const int targ = TBuilder::calc_targ(prev_targ);
        using built_type = typename TBuilder::template type<targ>;

        // recurse
        using further_types = typename helper<targ, TBuilders2...>::type;

        // concatenate tuple
        using type = tuple_cat_types<std::tuple<built_type>, further_types>;
    };

    // concatenate tuple with First_mod
    using type = tuple_cat_types<std::tuple<First_mod<first_targ>>,
                     typename helper<first_targ, TBuilders...>::type>;
};


int main()
{
    gen<First_mod<3>, A_builder<5>, B_builder<2>>::type x;
    static_assert(std::tuple_size<decltype(x)>::value == 3, "!");
    std::get<0>(x).print();
    std::get<1>(x).print();
    std::get<2>(x).print();
}
```

---

Slightly easier with a builder for `First_mod`:

```
template<int param>
struct First_builder
{
    static constexpr int calc_targ(int /* discarded */)
    {
        return param;
    }

    template < int targ >
    using type = First_mod<targ>;
};

/* ... */

// the generator of the tuple
template < int prev_targ, typename... TBuilders >
struct gen
{  using type = std::tuple<>;  };

template < int prev_targ, typename TBuilder, typename... TBuilders2 >
struct gen<prev_targ, TBuilder, TBuilders2...>
{
    // build type using builder
    static const int targ = TBuilder::calc_targ(prev_targ);
    using built_type = typename TBuilder::template type<targ>;

    // recurse
    using further_types = typename gen<targ, TBuilders2...>::type;

    // concatenate tuple
    using type = tuple_cat_types<std::tuple<built_type>, further_types>;
};


int main()
{
    const int discarded = 0;
    gen<discarded, First_builder<3>, A_builder<5>, B_builder<2>>::type x;
    static_assert(std::tuple_size<decltype(x)>::value == 3, "!");
    std::get<0>(x).print();
    std::get<1>(x).print();
    std::get<2>(x).print();
}
```

Comment: (I'm still commenting / providing some documentation.)

Comment: @gorill Generally, you use recursion for these kind of things. The specific tricks here are: 1) make the builder as useful as possible 2) don't recurse via inheritance but via nested typedef (to be able to use static members and nested typedefs) 3) concatenate tuples